# Should questions about using EE software and tools be closed?

Tags: discussion

I was reviewing close votes and was at first tempted to jump on the bandwagon and close this question (for which the 4 close votes are classifying it as a question about the *use* of electronics rather than design):

[For QuestaSim, what's the difference between vsim.exe and vsimk.exe](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/592731/2028)

But upon more careful consideration, I've definitely seen questions about EE software and tools on the site before and they've generally been acceptable.

To me, this question meets several criteria:

- It's on-topic, as it's related to EE design
- It seems possible to help future visitors/searchers
- This community is probably the best one to ask, short of a product support forum

Possible cons:

- Software updates/better documentation, etc. could render the question obsolete.
- Depending on the software/tool, its applicability for future visitors may be minimal (only two followers of the tag for that tool in question).

What is the consensus on EE software/tool *usage* questions? Should this question actually be closed?

Comment: I've closed it basically because it's asking about why windows hangs on version A vs not hanging on version B. I think it's also a dangerous game to start supporting all but the basic core tools an EE needs. If the software doesn't have a good forum then it's a P.o.S in my book and doesn't deserve support on this site.

Comment: @Andyaka You have some good points. I was focusing on the core of the question which was `what's the difference between vsim.exe and vsimk.exe?` and felt that might be useful to others.

Answer (score 4):

**It should stay open.**

I feel that the pros listed here outweigh the negatives and, especially since it has what appears to be a useful answer, should stay open. (I suspect the close votes may be premature or did not consider the nature of the software being asked about.)

Answer (score 4):

EE software tool questions have always been on-topic here. But it has to be a tool more or less exclusively used for electronics design. Question examples:

**On-topic**

- Schematics editors and PCB CAD software.
- Electronics or RF simulators.
- Firmware compilers, debuggers, simulators/emulators.
- FPGA software, simulators and tools. Including those for VHDL or Verilog like the example from the question.
- PLC programming software and tools.
- Electronics production/assembly software.

**Off-topic**

- General/mechanical engineering CAD software.
- General programming tools and IDE, version control systems, databases (ask on SO)
- PC/general computer questions.
- Business software, project management software, office suites